# Dropdown Menu Entaglement

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently making a dropdown menu. It's functional, but I want to tie in a color change to the button that is linked to the displaying of the hidden content of the menu. when the content is shown, I want the button's background color to change to a gradient, and return to its other color when the user clicks away from the dropdown contents.

Heres the javascript:

```
//Toggle dropdown menu
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
} 

function myFunction2() {
  document.getElementbyId("dbutton").classList.toggle("shine"); }

window.onclick = function(event) {
if(!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var btn = document.getElementsByClassName('dropbtn');
    var i
        for (i=0; i < btn.length; i++){ 
        var btnshine = btn[i]
        if (btnshine.classList.contains('shine')) {
        btnshine.classList.remove('shine');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and the CSS:

```
   /* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
   background-color: #f2f2f2;
  color: #333333;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position:fixed;
  z-index:3;
  width:100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px white;
}

/* Dropdown button hover & focus */
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  -moz-animation: hilite2 1s infinite;
}


/*container*/
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display:block;
  width:100%
  z-index:2;
}

/* Dropdown Content */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px white;
  z-index: 2;
}



/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding-top:1px;
  padding-bottom:1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline;
  width:50%;
  text-align:center;

/* Show the dropdown menu */
.show {display:block; } 

.shine {-moz-animation: hilite2 1s infinite:}

@keyframes hilite2{
0%{color:white;background-color:#7f618a;}
50%{color:white; background-color:#e2acf5;}
100%{color:white; background-color:#734783;}
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction();myFunction2()" class="dropbtn" id="dbutton">______________</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="../backdrops/banner.jpg"></li>
    
        <li><a href="../thevault.html" onClick="kill()">log out</a></li>    
    </ul>
    
  </div>
```

what on earth am I doing wrong???

Comment: Hi, do you mean 'gradient' in the same sense that CSS uses it (linear-gradient etc) or in the sense where you seem to be using it - changing color gradually? Also, you have a -moz in front of the animation setting - what browser are you using?

Comment: You also have a typo in the JS - getElementbyId instead of getElementById - you may like to look at the console in your browser's dev tools to check. Could you put your code into a working snippet so that we can look at it further.

Comment: You also have a : instead of a ; at the end of the .shine definition. Removing your several syntactic errors makes the code work (assuming the definition of 'gradient' is not in the usual CSS sense, see first comment).